# Vim Color Scheme Problems on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: vim, ubuntu, xterm

When I change my color scheme in command-line Vim on Ubuntu 11.04, stripes on the bottom and right of the terminal (xterm) refuse to change color. While I can select any color scheme that I like, the two bands of color will remain at the default set for my xterm profile. Here's a link to an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcpni.png) to illustrate what I describe; my best guess is that xterm is not playing well with fullscreen mode in Unity. Do you have any suggestions for things I should try in order to fix this?

Comment: By "stripe" you mean the command line, right? It's a bit hard to see, but it seems black while the rest of your background is gray-ish.

Comment: Could you post your vimrc and the colorscheem in question somewhere?

Comment: This happens even when my vimrc is blank; this particular color scheme is xoria256.

Comment: Any reason why this question was marked as off-topic? I see plenty of other ones like it to the side that deal with specific OS problems for Vim, so I thought posting here would be alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim is applying its colors to individual character cells.

Your expanded xterm window's width and height are probably not divisible by the width and height of a single character cell.

With my own font settings, a cell is 7 px by 15 px.

My display is 1600px wide and 1200 px tall, a fullscreen xterm would cover the entire area but the available cells would only cover an area of 1594 px * 1200 px, leaving a tiny 4 px wide vertical band on the right and — luckily — fit the whole height.

I see one easy way to get rid of your "stripes": set the background color of xterm to the same color you use in your colorscheme or vice-versa.

Comment: I tried what you suggested before, but it's still a pain if I want to cycle through my color schemes. I guess I could try to make a script in Vim to set the background color in xterm to that of the color scheme.